# Query to return true only if all of its records have null in a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, count, having-clause, sql-null

Let's suppose there is a table **assignments** and its columns are

- assignment_id
- assignor
- task_id
- assignee

The same task_id can be assigned by assignor to more than 1 assignees.
At the moment i have a task that is assigned to 2 assigness. Let's see my example in the following table:

```
+---------------+----------+---------+----------+
| assignment_id | assignor | task_id | assignee | 
+---------------+--------------------+----------+
|       1       |    a1    |    t1   |    x1    | 
+---------------+----------+---------+----------+
|       2       |    a1    |    t1   |    x2    | 
+---------------+----------+---------+----------+
```

When the assignor removes an assignee the table looks as follows:

```
+---------------+----------+---------+----------+
| assignment_id | assignor | task_id | assignee | 
+---------------+--------------------+----------+
|       1       |    a1    |    t1   |    x1    | 
+---------------+----------+---------+----------+
|       2       |    a1    |    t1   |   null   | 
+---------------+----------+---------+----------+
```

Now, i need a query that returns true only when each record of this specific task_id has null value in assignee column.
What i have written so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT task_id, nulls, total,

    (CASE
        WHEN nulls = total then true
        ELSE false
    END) unassigned
    
FROM

(
SELECT task_id, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM assignments b WHERE assignee IS NULL AND b.task_id = a.task_id) 'nulls',
(SELECT count(*) FROM assignments b WHERE b.task_id = a.task_id) 'total'

FROM assignments a 

WHERE assignee is NULL) c
```

and the outcome is:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| task_id | nulls | total | unassigned | 
+--------------------------------------+
|    1    |   2   |   2   |     1      | 
+---------+-------+-------+------------+
```

Any suggestions on improving my query or completely replace it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you could just use aggregation:

```
select assignment_id,
    count(*) - count(assignee) as nulls,
    count(*) as total,
    case when count(assignee) = 0 then 1 else 0 end as unassigned
from assignments
group by assignment_id
```

If you want to filter on assignments that are unassigned, then you can add a `having` clause at the end of the query:

```
having count(assignee) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need only 2 columns: the `task_id` and the number of rows with `null`s in `assignee`.
So `group by taskid` and set the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select task_id, count(*) total
from assignments
group by task_id
having max(assignee) is null
```

The condition `having max(assignee) is null` returns only the `taskid`s that have only `null`s in the column `assignee`.